# Add additional items in Combobox with enum values

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using a wpf combobox for displaying and selecting enum "BloodGroup" The BloodGroup Enum is defined as under.

```
    public enum BloodGroup : byte {
    A_Positive,
    A_Negative,
    B_Positive,
    B_Negative,
    AB_Positive,
    AB_Negative,
    O_Positive,
    O_Negative,
    }
```

Here is the wpf combobox code that I use to populate combobox with enum items above.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BloodGroupEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enums:BloodGroup" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox x:Name="BloodGroupFilter" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BloodGroupEnum}}" 
              cal:Message.Attach = "[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action BloodGroupFilterChanged(BloodGroupFilter)]"/>
```

I am using the above combobox to filter rows of datagrid. To cancel the filter I need additional item in combobox displaying **"Cancel Filter"**. How do I add an additional item 
in the above combobox which will be used to cancel the filter.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Got it. Will not repeat in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine different collections with `CompositeCollection`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="BloodGroupFilter">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource BloodGroupEnum}}"/>
            <sys:String>Cancel Filter</sys:String>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: That looks promising, but how do I pass value(say -1) to ViewModel,  indicating that "Cancel Filter" is selected? I tried using Tag but could not get the value in my ViewModel

Comment: @Nirvan, an obvious way is to create a separate enum with `Cancel_Filter = 0xFF` (as -1 is not a valid value for `byte`). Another solution is using `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` properties of the `ComboBox`.